# Need to sent onclick event string var from hyperlink to javascript event function(e)?

Tags: javascript, variables, event-handling

Can someone tell me how i can sent a string from an onclick event to the searchfunction?
onclick="SearchFunction("mystring"); -->This doesnt works.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var SearchFunction = function(e) {
            searchwords=$("#q").val();
             STR=??? -->Needs to get the string from the onclick hyperlink.

        };
        $("#q").keyup(SearchFunction);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).text()` should do it.

Comment: could u give me an example with the a href onclick event?

Comment: Same way as you have done for the keyup. $("#IDOfa").click(SearchFunction);

Comment: i have tried this: adding $('#url').click(SearchFunction); and using url: <a href="#" id="url">mylink</a> How can i sent a variabele to the STR=?? above? with that a href link?

Comment: I got it almost working :( I tried: var str=$("#url").text(); and $('#url').click(SearchFunction); Then str will be the name of my url called mylink, but i want to let mylink sent a value for example value=4.  <a href="#" id="url" value="4">mylink</a> and .val doesnt work.

Comment: str==$("#url").val(); $('#url').click(SearchFunction); <a href="#" id="url" value="test">mylink</a> THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!